# Exporting procedurally textured models for game engine

Tags: texturing, materials, export, shaders, procedural

Recently I created a model which was texured procedurally. I used noise texture to texture the model and also combined it with a bump and Vorenoi map to add extra geometry to my model. On exporting the model neither my texture nor my geometry was preserved. Different export formats rendered different results but none of them preserved the texture or geometry. Is there a way around this problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to bake textures? Or are you asking if there is a way to export the node setup? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Blender's node system cannot be exported since the 3D formats aren't able to store them and the game engines do not have nodes that are equivalent to the ones found in Blender.

What you need to do is bake your textures. Generally for game models you start with a high poly, detailed model from which you create the low poly version that can be used by the game engine (or several for different level of details - LODs). Part of the process is baking the normal map and PBR textures in order to get as close as possible to the look of the high poly model while keeping the polycount low. This is to ensure good performance of the game and keeping vertex budget for hero props (a building in the distant background doesn't need as many polygons as the model of your main character).

Comment: [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/YsXe11YA7AM?t=311) by Aidy Burrows may help you get started if you want to use Blender similar to Substance Designer for creating procedural materials.